# Problem in selecting a value in dropdown javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, console, dropdown

This is the drop-down.

```
<select
  id="identity.dvsSourceList.0.issuingState.value"
  name="identity.dvsSourceList.0.issuingState.value"
  class="native black-60"
  required=""
  data-invalid=""
>
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
  <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
  <option value="NT">NT</option>
  <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
  <option value="SA">SA</option>
  <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
  <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
  <option value="WA">WA</option>
</select>
```

I tried executing this:

```
document.querySelector('identity.dvsSourceList.0.issuingState.value').value= "VIC";
```

But it gave this error:

```
VM252:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'identity.dvsSourceList.0.issuingState.value' is not a valid selector.
    at <anonymous>:1:10
```

Answer (score 3):

Selecting a value in dropdown javascript the problem with your id naming convention because you are using `**.**` You can use an attribute selector like this example:

```js
    $("[id='identity.dvsSourceList.0.issuingState.value']").val("VIC");
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <select
          id="identity.dvsSourceList.0.issuingState.value"
          name="identity.dvsSourceList.0.issuingState.value"
          class="native black-60"
          required=""
          data-invalid=""
        >
          <option value="">Please select</option>
          <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
          <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
          <option value="NT">NT</option>
          <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
          <option value="SA">SA</option>
          <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
          <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
          <option value="WA">WA</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `#` to select based on id, and you will need backslashes to escape the dots, preventing them from being interpreted as class names. However, you should really consider using less complicated ids without any special characters.

```js
document.querySelector('#identity\\.dvsSourceList\\.0\\.issuingState\\.value').value= "VIC";
```

```html
<select
  id="identity.dvsSourceList.0.issuingState.value"
  name="identity.dvsSourceList.0.issuingState.value"
  class="native black-60"
  required=""
  data-invalid=""
>
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
  <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
  <option value="NT">NT</option>
  <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
  <option value="SA">SA</option>
  <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
  <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
  <option value="WA">WA</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.querySelector('#identity\\.dvsSourceList\\.0\\.issuingState\\.value').value= "VIC"
```

Use prefix `#` with the an `id` and `.` with a class when using `querySelector`. Another thing is, in order to select an HTML element by ID that contains dots, you need to escape it using double slash `\\`.